# running db2 in bash from git's mingw on windows

Tags: windows, bash, db2, mingw

I have a shell script that runs a few db2 commands which I want to use on windows.
When running this in bash from msysgit 2.5.3 64bit I get an error from db2:

> SQL1024N  Die Verbindung zur Datenbank ging verloren.  SQLSTATE=08003

for instance
start db2 with `db2cmd` then, 
start the bash from the db2cmd window,
then run

```
db2 connect to <db> user <user>
db2 select * from syscat.tables
```

The db2 select will produce the same error.

This happens because the bash will start another subshell to execute each db2 command and the db2 connect calls another process db2bp which actually holds the connection.
When db2 connect returns the subshell is closed and the connection is lost.
This happens also when I concatenate the commands with ; or &&.

Is there a way to make bash not execute a subshell or at least not for every command?

Comment: Have you tried putting all statements into a single file and then passing the file to the "db2" command? A parameter "-f filename" can be used to pass an input file to DB2.

Comment: This doesnt work in my case because I am using the results of these statements in my script. The reason is twofold. 1. I would get the connect and connect reset messages in the db2 result which i'd need to parse out afterwards which i do not want to. 2. I am using different select whose results i'd also need to differntiate between.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method for preventing to spawn a new shell is to prefix each command with a dot (some references for example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/whats-the-meaning-of-a-dot-before-a-command-in-shell)). You may also examine the shell built-in `exec` command. However, I am afraid that running a shell in Windows will have its own oddities, at least judging from my own experience, so you may want to try to experiment with different shell flavours before you get the solution right. Hope it helps anyway!

Comment: the dot method only works for calling scripts, which the db2 executable is not. the exec command does something completely different, it executes a command that replaces the current shell.

Answer (score -1):

For Scripting in Bash you should add, after the connect string this little Bugger:
export DB2DBDFT=
That will ensure that all further subshells will use your db2 connection.
Hope this solves your problem.